# Homeomorphism from $(-1,1)$ to $\mathbb R$

Tags: functions, soft-question, metric-spaces, continuity

I know that $f: (-1,1) \to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=\tan \Big(\dfrac{\pi}2x \Big)$ is a homeomorphism . I am looking for some other homeomorphism between $(-1,1)$ and $\mathbb R$ which is not in such trigonometric form ; preferably algebraic , or at least in logarithmic or exponential form . Please help

Comment: It interesting that there is no rational function $f$ that is a homeomorphism $f: (-1,1) \to \mathbb R$.  Simeon showed that it could be the inverse of a rational function.

Comment: For an "exponential" form you could use a hyperbolic tangent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
x \mapsto \frac{x}{1-x^2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

STEP 1:
*Any two bounded open intervals are homeomorphic:* you scale it up by the ratio of their lengths after moving the left end point of one to the other.

STEP 2: Whole real line is homeomorphic to semi-infinite open interval:

$y=e^x$ carries the whole real line bijectively to positive real line.

STEP 3: A semi infinite real line and a bounded open interval are homeomorphic:
For example $y=\frac1x$ provides a homeomorphism between $(0,1)$ and $(0,\infty)$.

Stitching these three together would be a fun exercise giving what you want.